# What downloadable data sources exist for getting country from latitude, longitude, and date?

Tags: geolocation, location, gis

I have seen countless questions asking about converting latitude / longitude coordinates into country, state, town, etc., but I found no question which includes a time component. I have tried many searches, but only seem to be able to get isolated data sources by year or real-time APIs, not any open source data with a time component.

As an example using United States recognition, the coordinates (42.635832, 20.946381) would show Kosovo today, but in 2005 would show Serbia, and would at some point further in the past show Yugoslavia.

The question is, what data source can be used to retrieve country from latitude, longitude, and date? The ideal granularity would be day, ideal source of authority would be US recognition. The ideal data format would be some sort of structured shape data with start and end dates for validity.

Comment: this is a hard problem, a start for the British Isles can be found at http://visionofbritain.org that is the result of 20 years work by a team of researchers (though to be fair it includes census statistics for many of the areas too).

Comment: interesting problem, but not sure if stackoverflow is the right place for it!  searching for various terms points me at things like https://researchguides.library.vanderbilt.edu/gis/historical but would be a large amount of work to put everything together, especially if all you want is country names